# how to select single column data in infragistics igniteui grid

Tags: jsonp, infragistics, ignite-ui

how to select data of single column from a grid data.
The grid data is passed as following:

```
var url = "/Main/Grid?tbname="+parameter;
var jsonp = new $.ig.JSONPDataSource({
           dataSource: url, paging: {
               enabled: true, pageSize: 10,
               type: "remote"
           }
       });
```

$("#listingGrid").igGrid("dataSourceObject", jsonp).igGrid("dataBind");

I have to retrieve data in another page from this grid and select one column from this data.

and i have retrieved data like this

```
var ds = window.parent.$("#listingGrid").igGrid("option", "dataSource");
```

but not able to access one column data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that since you are using the [DataSource](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2013.1/ig.jsonpdatasource) directly that you don't want the actual columns in the grid, which might differ from the columns in the data source depending on how you have the grid set up.

The easiest way to go about this would probably be to call the data function off of the data source once you retrieve it from your other page.  This function returns an array of objects that are the items in each row.  Once you have that you can iterate over each of the items and query the individual property.

```
var ds = window.parent.$('#listingGrid').igGrid('option', 'dataSource');

$.each(ds.data(), function (i, item) {
    var itemProperty = item.Property;
    // ...
});
```

You'll need to make sure that the data is all loaded from the service first though or data will possibly return an empty array.

Comment: you mention making sure all the data is loaded from the service first. I think i am running into that issue now. I have combo box column a iggrid that needs to be populated from a service. when i open the editor dialog the column is not populated. What hooks can i register to make sure my combo box gets populated before the editor window is open/during opening.