# select single column data in igniteui grid

Tags: jquery, grid, datasource

I am interested in this subject [how to select single column data in infragistics igniteui grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545057/how-to-select-single-column-data-in-infragistics-igniteui-grid/22868068?noredirect=1#comment34890496_22868068) 
. Can you please tell me how to retrieve the data of a specific column ?

I have the following :

I would like to write a message if one of the values of that column is different of 1.

I wrote the following if ('${valueID}' != 1) { alert ("OK!!!") }

But I am always getting the alert even if the value is = 1

I found the above solution (which is what I need) but I didn't know how to use it.

I copied the solution
var ds = window.parent.$("#contactGrid").igGrid('option', 'dataSource');

$.each(ds.data(), function (i, item) {
    var itemProperty = item.Property;

})
But I did't know how to proceed.

I want to loop on the signle column valuID and if each row is different from 1 show the alert.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the job for you:

```
ds = $("#contactGrid").igGrid("option", "dataSource");
$.each(ds, function (i, item) {
  if(item.valulID != 1) {
    alert("OK !");
  }                         
})
```